# how to make fat line evry 2 rows in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to make fat line evry 2 rows in DataGridView ?

(evry 2 rows i want that the grid will have fat line)

thank's in advance

Comment: Gold, about the tags: C# does not have a DataGrid but  WPF, WinForms and Asp.NET do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [DataGridView.CellFormatting event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)